# How to display the string without 0

Tags: ios, swift, string

I try to eliminate the 0 at the end of string. right now what i have is (Return "2101999.0000")

```
let point = newObject["PtsBal"] as! String
```

i use

```
NSNumberRFormatter()
```

but i dont know where i did wrong. i need to display it back in this as a string.

```
self.detailArr = ["\((self.userInfo!["FirstName"] as! String).capitalizedString) \((self.userInfo!["LastName"] as! String).capitalizedString)", point, ""]
```

Comment: you no need of .0000 this correct

Comment: add your original value, and you are need value.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik yep im trying to throw 0 away. only need to display "2101999". what i mean is it will eliminate all type of string that have 0 in their end

Comment: @AyusSalleh - check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 let point = newObject["PtsBal"] as! String
 let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle


    if let number = formatter.numberFromString(point) {
        // number is an instance of NSNumber
        point = String(number.integerValue)

    }
```

you get the output as

[image]

finally append the string where you need

```
self.detailArr = ["\((self.userInfo!["FirstName"] as! String).capitalizedString) \((self.userInfo!["LastName"] as! String).capitalizedString)", point, ""]
```

Comment: the following Int(point) have a new error "Cannot convert value of type 'Int?' to expected element type of 'String'

Comment: look like it throw everything after decimal point. can i just print if the value is "2101999.0010" it will display only "2101999.001"

Comment: @AyusSalleh - little bit confuse what teh output you expect

Comment: i tried to throw all 0 after the last value that >0 so if 
example 1: "2101999.0010"
expected : "2101999.001"

example 2: "2101999.1000"
expected: ""2101999.1"

Answer (score 1):

You can simply remove all characters after (.) dot

```
var str = "2101999.0000"
if let dotRange = str.rangeOfString(".") {
    str.removeRange(dotRange.startIndex..<str.endIndex)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this single line of Code
```

let number : Int = NSString(string: YourString).integerValue

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `point` is always a string representing a floating point value you could use

```
let point = "2101999.0000"
let number = "\(Int(Double(point)!))"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let string = "2101999.0000"
let result = string.characters.split{$0 == "."}.map(String.init)
print (result[0])
```

Comment: You should add some text explaining what your code does and why.